# SignalR changing hub subscription

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a simple app, which displays a list of available signalR hubs. A user selects a hub and it connects to it, this subscribes an event to add messages to a table on the page. The user can then send messaged to that hub which will also fire the subscription adding that message to the table. This all works great.

Now if the user selects another hub, the app connects and sets up a new subscription, however the original subscription still fires causing duplicate messages to be added to the table. Each time the hub is changed further subscriptions get added causing one send to result in many messages in the table.

I have tried disconnecting the hub, disposing the hub and trying to remove the subscription with hubProxy.off(eventName), but nothing seems to work, other than a page reload.

Here is the code I have just added the onHub changed function as this is where everything is happening.

Any ideas appreciated. :)

```
function HubViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.hubConnection = '';
    self.hub = '';

    $.getScript("../signalR/hubs");

    self.hubs = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedHub = ko.observable();
    self.messageText = ko.observable();
    self.messageCollection = ko.observableArray();

    self.hubChanged = function () {

        // Setup hub connection.
        $.connection.hub.url = "../signalR";
        self.hubConnection = $.hubConnection();

        // Get the selected hub name.
        var selectedHubName;
        _.each(self.hubs(), function(item) {
            if (item.hubId == self.selectedHub()) {
                selectedHubName = item.hubName;
            }
        });

        // Check for a selected connection
        if (self.selectedHub()) {

            // Create proxy.
            self.hub = self.hubConnection.createHubProxy(selectedHubName);

            // Remove any existing listener(s).
            self.hub.off('addNewMessageToPage');

            // Setup listener.
            self.hub.On('addNewMessageToPage', function (sender, message) {
                self.messageCollection().push({ hubName: selectedHubName, name: selectedHubName, message: message, dateTime: new Date().toLocaleString() });
                $('#hubMessageGrid').dxDataGrid('instance').refresh();
            });

            // start connection.
            self.hubConnection.start()
                .done(function() {
                    toastr.success('hub connected');
                    $('#sendMessageButton').click(function() {
                        self.hub.invoke('sendAll', 'hub management page', self.messageText());
                        self.messageText('');
                    });

                })
                .fail(function(error) {
                    toastr.error('hub connection ' + error);
                });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to disconnect the hub first by calling the self.hub.stop(); function

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the exact same handler instance when unsubscribing. Passing a different instance (even if the function body is the same) will not remove the handler.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/signalr/hubconnection?view=signalr-js-latest#off-string---args--any-------void-